# What's wrong in how I'm solving Buffon's needles?

Tags: probability, geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> 2. Buffon’s needle revisited. Two grids of parallel lines are superimposed: the first grid contains
>    lines distance a apart, and the second contains lines distance b apart which are perpendicular to those
>    of the first set. A needle of length r (< min{a, b}) is dropped at random. Show that the probability it
>    intersects a line equals r(2a + 2b − r)/(πab).

So I routinely model the situation as : I restrict myself to a rectangle of the grid where $X,Y$ correspond to the coordinates of the needle's midpoint, that follow a uniform distribution respectively on $[0,a]$ and $[0,b]$, and $\Theta$ corresponds to the angle the needle makes with the $x$-axis, it follows a uniform distribution on $[0,\pi]$. $X,Y,\Theta$ are mutually independent and their joint probability density function is $f_{X,Y,\Theta}(x,y,\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi ab}$ with $x,y,\theta$ being in the right intervals.

At this point, technically I know that it's faster to calculate the probability of the event that corresponds to no intersection to get the complementary, but here I decide to begin by calculating the probability of the intersection with the vertical lines of the grid, let's call this event $V$. By a quick diagram of the situation, I deduce very much analogously to the simpler Buffon's needles problem that the set that corresponds to having an intersection with the vertical axis is : $\frac{r}{2}cos(\theta) \geq X$ or $\frac{r}{2}cos(\theta) \geq a - X$.

The problem arises when I try to calculate the probability by integrating :

$\mathbb{P}(V) =  \frac{1}{\pi a} \int_0^\pi (\int_0^{\frac{r}{2}cos(\theta)}dx + \int_{a-\frac{r}{2}cos(\theta)}^{a}dx) d\theta $

I get :

$\mathbb{P}(V) = \frac{r}{\pi a} \int_0^\pi cos(\theta) d\theta = 0$

Which is obviously false, but I can't seem to spot my mistake!

I've noticed on the internet that people tend to prefer the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ for $\theta$, which would indeed solve my problem and give me the value $\frac{r}{a \pi}$ which seems coherent with what we get in the vertical case. But first of all, I don't really understand why modulo $\pi/2$ is enough to fully identify our needle's position, and also I've checked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem#Laplace%27s_extension_(short_needle_case)) where they seem to use the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ with success which is coherent with my choice of the modulo $\pi$. It would give me another result that is $\frac{2r}{a \pi}$ which is really weird!

**EDIT:**

Ok it was just a silly mistake on my part. To get the horizontal half-span on the needle I immediately multiplied the needle'shalf-length by $cos(\theta)$ without checking the sign of the result that can be negative when $\theta \in (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi]$. So I need to take $|cos(\theta)|$ instead to get a positive horizontal half-span, or restrict $\theta$ to $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ because $\theta$ and $\pi - \theta$ have the same horizontal and vertical half-span and both $cos(\theta)$ and $sin(\theta)$ are nonnegative on this updated interval.

Comment: In your $\mathbb{P}(V)$ integral, consider what happens when $\frac\pi2 <\theta < \pi$: you get $\frac r2\cos(\theta)<0$ and so in effect a reversed integration and a negative probability.

Comment: You might also want to check the density function $\left(\frac1{\pi a}\right)$ you are using in the integral

Comment: Oh ok I see thank you for your answer, and it doesn't show up for the vertical case because $sin$ is nonnegative on $[0, \pi]$, so I should be careful to restrict $\theta$ to $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ because $\theta$ and $\pi - \theta$ have the same half-horizontal span and if I choose $[0, \pi]$ I should change $cos(\theta)$ to $|cos(\theta)|$ since I'll be counting the same span twice but dividing it accordingly. 

What's wrong with the density function though?